# loading the template based on url parameters in django

Tags: javascript, django, python-2.7

I want to load the login page based on different url parameters. I am using django.contrib.auth.login mechanism as a login mechanism. I have login template. I also had certain condition which hit my javascript where i am redirecting the user to the login page . Something like :

```
Windows.loaction =/login/?auth=false
```

but this time i want to load the login with some extra content in it . What changes i have to made in urls.py and in my template to achieve this.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no experience about Nifti.  The image data would appear to be in `nii.img`. You can access the first slice with `variable=nii.img(:,:,1)`, the second slice with `variable=nii.img(:,:,2)`.  You can then store these in a .mat file with eg. `save('data.mat','variable')`. If you're working with sinogram data, then you would ofcourse need to combine the slices into one image.

Comment: @mfkin ..thanks there is one thing any idea how can store all the slice i.e complete 3D image into a variable? i can visualise the image using 'variable =imshow(nii.img(:,:, 2),[])'